# Perl-like regular expression in Qt. Using /gs in Qt

Tags: regex, qt

I have some regexp with /gs
Those regexp work on [RegExr](http://ww.gskinner.com/RegExr/)

Why can i use /gs in Qt with QRegExp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For perl-like `/g`, you need a [loop](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qregexp.html#cap-in-a-loop)

By default, `QRegExp` pattern `.` matches any character so it works the same as `/s`.

Further reading: http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qregexp.html#notes-for-perl-users

Comment: Thank you. I reorganized my regular expressions, but your answer - this is what I wanted to know.